# Developing a Shapefile using MATLAB Mapping Toolbox using Object Oriented Programming

Tags: oop, mapping, matlab

I'm using MATLAB (Mapping Toolbox) to create a large number of lines between different countries. Since there are so many lines, I'm trying to do this using object-oriented programming.

The problem is that I've created a lot of objects (lines) from the class, 'Transline', but when I try to export the whole set as a shape-file using the 'shapewrite' command, MATLAB tells me that it's invalid because the 'shapewrite' command expects an input argument of type 'struct' rather than 'Transline' (which is the class of these objects). Is there any way I can use object-oriented programming to export the set of lines as a shapefile?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would think your best option is to simply call `struct(myObjs)`on your object before passing it to shapewrite. If the output of the structure is not in the correct format you can overload the struct method in your object. eg.

```
methods
   function myStructOfObj=struct(obj)
             %create correct structure
   end
end
```

Comment: Thank you, but can you please tell me where to write this code? I actually want to create more than 50 lines (each line being an object) and convert the whole set, instead of individual lines, into a struct. 

If I write this at the end of my code, where I am creating the objects, it only converts the first one into a struct and neglects the others. If I incorporate it into my class definition file, e.g., as a method, it doesn't have any effect at all

Comment: I finally figured it out! Thanks for your answer; it really helped a lot!

Comment: Glad to assist, so I guess you figured the struct method is not recursively called down the tree of your object.

Comment: Yes, because even if I include the struct function as a method in my class definition file (the name of the class is 'Transmissionline'), any object that I create from that class still belongs to that class type (Transmissionline) rather than a 'struct'. So, in the code where I was creating the objects (translines), I added this command after every object call:

basetranslines(1,i) = struct(transline);
i = i+1;

And then I used basetranslines as my mapstruct for the shapewrite command. The only disadvantage of this approach is that I have to copy and paste two additional lines for each object.